# Pandas: How return all rows if column string contains at least a certain number of strings from a list?

Tags: python, pandas

Say that I have a list of strings, such as

```
listStrings = [ 'cat', 'bat', 'hat', 'dad', 'look', 'ball', 'hero', 'up']
```

Is there a way would return all rows if a particular column contains 3 or more of the strings from the list?

For example

If the column contained 'My dad is a hero for saving the cat'

Then the row would be returned.

But if the column only contained 'the cat and bat teamed up  to find some food'

That row wouldn't be returned.

The only way I can think of is to get every combination of 3 from the list of strings, and use AND statements. e.g. 'cat' AND 'bat' AND 'hat'.

But this doesn't seem computationally efficient nor pythonic.

Is there a more efficient, compact way to do this?

Edit

Here is a pandas example

```
import pandas as pd 

listStrings = [ 'cat', 'bat', 'hat', 'dad', 'look', 'ball', 'hero', 'up']

df = pd.DataFrame(['test1', 'test2', 'test3'], ['My dad is a hero for saving the cat', 'the cat and bat teamed up to find some food', 'The dog found a bowl'])
df.head()


0
My dad is a hero for saving the cat test1
the cat and bat teamed up to find some food test2
The dog found a bowl    test3
```

So using the `listStrings`, I would like row 1 returned, but not row 2 or row 3.

Comment: If you make the effort to show an example dataframe, I could make the effort to answer ;-). I am sorry, but I am too lazy to write the dataframe required to test possible ways.

Comment: Just updated the prompt include a minimal pandas example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use set itersection:

```
import pandas as pd 

listStrings =  {'A', 'B'}    
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['A B', 'B C', 'C D']})

df = df.loc[df.text.apply(lambda x: len(listStrings.intersection(x.split())) >= 2)]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  text
0  A B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a set from the list strings. Make a function that takes the row and checks if each word is in the set. Every time a word is in the set, increment a counter by 1. If the counter equals three return true. If the counter is less than 3 and you have finished checking the row, return False.

Apply this function to the row. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

O(n) space for the set O(m) complexity for each row (because a set is O(1) lookup for each word), where m is the size of the row.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a dataframe with the sentences as columns, and the words from `listStrings` as indices, with value 1 if the word is in the sentence, else 0.

When you sum that dataframe, you obtain a Series with same index as your example dataframe, and the value is the number of words in the sentence: you can use that to select the rows having (more than) a specific number of them.

Possible code:

```
resul = pd.DataFrame({ix:
                      [1 if word in ix.split() else 0 for word in listStrings]
                      for ix in df.index}).sum()
print(df[resul>=3])
```

It gives:

```
                                                 0
My dad is a hero for saving the cat          test1
the cat and bat teamed up to find some food  test2
```